# mysql python: check whether an input exists in database

Tags: python, mysql

Can anyone help? 
   I have created a mysql database called 'ice cream' and connected it to python 3.3.5. I have a table with 2 columns : "MemberID" and "Username". Now i want to ask whether the user is a member or not, if he replies yes, my next question is ask him to key in his memberID, how do i check whether his input exists in the "MemberID" column my database, and if it exists, how can i print his "Username"?

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='1234',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='icecream')

cursor = conn.cursor

Member_Ans=input("Are you a member? ")
if Member_Ans=="yes":
while True:     
    loginID=input("Please enter your member ID: ")
    # I don't know what code to type in this part...
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about the cursor object, it's got every method you'd need.

Refer: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm

```
query = "SELECT * from tablename where MemberID="
while True:     
    loginID=input("Please enter your member ID: ")
    tmp_query=query+loginID
    cursor.execute(tmp_query)
    if cursor.rowcount==1:
        ## Do your thing here
        break
conn.close()
```

Comment: query="SELECT Username from ValidMember where MemberID="
while True:     
     loginID=input("Please enter your member ID: ")
     tmp_query=query+loginID
     cursor.execute(tmp_query)        
     if cursor.rowcount==1:
           USERNAME=cursor.fetchone()
           print("Welcome, ",USERNAME, "!")

Comment: query="SELECT Username from ValidMember where MemberID="
while True:     
     loginID=input("Please enter your member ID: ")
     tmp_query=query+loginID
     cursor.execute(tmp_query)        
     if cursor.rowcount==1:
           USERNAME=cursor.fetchone()
           print("Welcome, ",USERNAME, "!") => it prints "Welcome, (Aaron,)!"   I don't want the (bracket and comma) when printing USERNAME, but how to solve it?

Comment: Try this, `USERNAME=USERNAME.strip('(').strip(')').strip(',')` , then print whatever you want. Also this is a cheap hack, there probably a lot better methods but this will suit your need I guess.

Comment: thanks! 'def Storage_Mass():
    
    
    for i in range (len(UserFlavor)):
        for i in range (len(UserFlavorPercentage)):
            cursor.execute("SELECT FlavorMass FROM StorageMass WHERE FlavorType='" +UserFlavor[i]+ "'")
            result=cursor.fetchone()

            FinalMass=result-((mass*(UserFlavorPercentage[i]/100.00))*TotalSet)
            sql=("UPDATE StorageMass SET FlavorMass=")
            cursor.execute(sql+FinalMass)
    conn.close()`

Comment: Now i have another problem, i got this error when i run the code mentioned in the previous comment:   < FinalMass=result-((mass*(UserFlavorPercentage[i]/100.00))*TotalSet)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'>

Comment: Hey, if this answer was helpful, then mark this as accepted answer and continue this conversation over chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101609/mysql-python-check-whether-an-input-exists-in-database

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow, and it says that i have to earn 20 reputation in order  to chat, so i can't chat at there. Can you help me to solve my last problem?